# bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, bibtex, natbib, biber

I've heard of many different bibliography-related packages/platforms/?. What's the difference between the following, which is good for what tasks, advantages/disadvantages, which one is the most modern, etc.:

- BibTeX
- [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)
- [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib)
- [Biber](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/)
- (If I missed anything important, please just add it here or answer about it)

---

**Background**

So far I've just typed in my citations (i.e. their sources) and lists of references manually (as regular footnotes/text) whichever way I needed them, but I'm considering switching to something more TeX-y. I usually use different literature for each paper, and I often have to switch between radically different styles for citations and the list of references, so flexibility is necessary. I'm trying to find out which platform would be the best for me, a hint at good introductory reading for whatever you recommend would be more than welcome.

Comment: @Joseph: I'm not sure if I agree with your edit. The markup and links imply that I (as OP) knew that `biblatex` and `natbib` are packages etc., which, honestly, wasn't the case. I just had these terms floating around in my head. Then again, you might argue that I could've found out about that at least by Googling.

Comment: I think it's less important what you knew, and more important that the question, as now phrased, is a good resource.

Comment: @doncherry I've taken the approach as Seamus outline, broadly, in that there is a wiki-like nature to the questions. In particular, as you mentioned things like `biblatex` it seemed reasonable that you'd heard of them _somewhere_, so a link to one possible place seemed reasonable. I hope I've not implied you'd read the linked material. Of course, if you're not happy then feel free to revert.

Comment: I wish **arXiv would fix their building system** rather than directing everybody here.
biblatex is so much nicer to use, the whole "it is not portable" claim by arXiv is utter nonsense.

Comment: What is `OP` in @doncherry's comment?

Comment: @EduardoReis Original poster, as https://www.google.com/search?q=OP%20meaning explains.

Answer (score 702, accepted):

(The following is an expansion of the [biblatex](/questions/tagged/biblatex) tag entry, which I helped to write).

### Some terminology

It's first off important to realize that the term BibTeX is often used to refer to various distinct things, and this can lead to some confusion. For example we typically tell new users to "use bibtex for your bibliography" which usually just means don't do it by hand, but instead store your references in a `.bib` file and use some automatic method of formatting citations and bibliography.  Additionally, we also talk about a "bibtex file" (i.e. a `.bib` file). Both of these uses are in reality quite vague, and part of the reason for this question is to distinguish among them more carefully.

So in this question we will use the following terms:

- `bibtex` and `biber` are external programs that process bibliography information and act (roughly) as the interface between your `.bib` file and your LaTeX document.
- `natbib` and `biblatex` are LaTeX packages that format citations and bibliographies; `natbib` works *only* with `bibtex`, while `biblatex` (at the moment) works with both `bibtex` and `biber`.)

For those users who already use `natbib`, and are contemplating a switch, the following question will also be useful: [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/2693).

### natbib

The `natbib` package has been around for quite a long time, and although still maintained, it is fair to say that it isn't being further developed.  It is still widely used, and very reliable.

**Advantages**

- It has a wide range of already developed `.bst` files which conform to many journals and publishers in the sciences.
- The author of the `natbib` package has written a package called `custom-bib`, which provides a utility called `makebst`. This utility is menu-driven and allows you to interactively generate custom bibliography style files. Bibliography style files generated with `makebst` are very stable and (unsurprisingly, given the authorship) work very well with `natbib`'s citation commands.
- The resulting bibliography code can be pasted directly into a document (often required for journal submissions). See [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/2693).

**Disadvantages**

- Because it depends on `bibtex`, its interface requires `.bst` files, which use a postfix language that is difficult to program in for most people. This means that making even minor modifications to an existing style to meet particular formatting requirements can be quite difficult.
- It is designed especially for Author-Year and (to a lesser extent) numeric citation styles that are common in the natural and social sciences. It is *not* able to do traditional humanities style citation styles such as Author/Title or footnote style citations and bibliographies (including various sorts of *ibid* tracking).
- Multiple bibliographies in a single document or categorized bibliographies require extra packages.
- By depending on `bibtex` as a backend, it inherits all of its disadvantages (see below).

You might want to use `natbib` if:

- there is a  `.bst` file already created for the specific journal you submitting a paper to;
- a journal accepts `latex` submissions and requires or expects `natbib`.  Such journal may not accept `biblatex` for the bibliography.

### biblatex

The `biblatex` package is being actively developed in conjunction with the `biber` backend.

**Advantages**

*Humanities style citations*

- `biblatex` is almost required if you need any of the following:
- humanities style citations (author-title type schemes; citations using *ibid* etc.)
- a much wider array of BibTeX database fields (again, especially suited for the humanities).
- Unicode encoded `.bib` files (usable with the `biber` replacement for `bibtex`).
- fine control over your own bibliography styles using regular `latex` methods.

*Author-year and numeric citations*

- `biblatex` provides the same functionality as `natbib` for author-year and numeric citations common in the natural and social sciences.  It can therefore be used as a replacement for `natbib`.

*General considerations*

- All formatting of citations and bibliography entries is done using regular LaTeX macros. As a consequence, regular LaTeX users are able to make modifications to existing styles quite easily. `biblatex` also has built in hooks for most kinds of modifications.
- Even though `biblatex` can use `bibtex` as a backend, it does no formatting with `.bst` files, but only uses `bibtex` for sorting.
- Multiple bibliographies and categorized bibliographies are supported directly.

**Available biblatex styles**

In addition to the standard styles that are documented in the `biblatex` manual, [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=biblatex&search_type=description) currently lists the following extra style packages for `biblatex`:

- [`biblatex-abnt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-abnt) ABNT (Brazil­ian As­so­ci­a­tion of Tech­ni­cal Norms) style for biblatex.
- [`biblatex-apa`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) APA style for biblatex.
- [`biblatex-chem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chem)  Chemistry styles for biblatex.
- [`biblatex-chicago`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago)    Chicago style files for biblatex.
- [`biblatex-dw`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-dw)  Humanities styles for biblatex.
- [`biblatex-historian`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-historian)    A Biblatex style based on Turabian.
- [`biblatex-ieee`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee)  IEEE style files for biblatex.
- [`biblatex-jura`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-jura)  Biblatex stylefiles for German legal literature.
- [`biblatex-mla`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-mla)    MLA style files for biblatex.
- [`biblatex-nature`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nature)  Biblatex support for the journal Nature.
- [`biblatex-philosophy`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy)  Styles for using biblatex for work in philosophy.
- [`biblatex-science`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-science)    Biblatex support for the journal Science.

Many new journal styles are being created for `biblatex`.  Given the flexibility of adapting `biblatex` styles, in many cases it may be quite easy to modify an existing style to accommodate a particular journal's style.

**Disadvantages**

- Journals and publishers may not accept documents that use `biblatex` if they have a house style with its own `natbib` compatible `.bst` file.
- It is not trivial to include the bibliographies created by `biblatex` into a document (as many publishers require.) See [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/2693).

### bibtex vs. biber

Many of the disadvantages of `natbib` are a consequence of its reliance on `bibtex` for formatting. This is the main (huge) distinction between the `natbib` and `biblatex`, as the latter, even when it uses `bibtex` as the backend, doesn't use it for formatting, only for sorting. However, `biblatex` is also designed to use `biber`, a new backend that adds further functionality to `biblatex`.

**bibtex**

*Advantages*

- very stable and widely used

*Disadvantages*

- very hard to modify bibliography styles without learning a different language (if using `natbib`; not an issue if using `biblatex`)
- very poor cross-language support and non-European script support. Non-ASCII characters are best avoided. See [How to write "ä" and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001) for guidance on how to write characters with accents and diacritics.

**biber**

*Advantages*

- able to deal with many more entry and field types in the `.bib` file.
- able to deal with UTF-8 encoded `.bib` files.
- better sorting control.

*Disadvantages*

- Only works with `biblatex`, not with `natbib`.
- Because it does much more than `bibtex` it is a lot slower. See [Why is biber so slow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53247/2693) for discussion.

### Differences between `.bib` files

As noted at the beginning of this answer, we tend to use the term `bibtex` file to refer to the `.bib` file itself, which leads to the assumption that tools that manipulate `.bib` files are only available to `bibtex` users and not `biber` users.  This is simply not the case: tools designed for manipulating `.bib` files such as reference managers and various `.bib` file generation/manipulation tools can be used.

It is the case, however, that as you transition to using all the features of `biber`/`biblatex` you may find certain differences in the `.bib` files become more relevant.

A separate question [Compatibility of bibtex and biblatex bibliography files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37095/2693) explores some of the differences between traditional `bibtex` `.bib` files and `.bib` files that have been adapted for use with `biber` and `biblatex`.

Comment: There is also my [historische-zeitschrift](http://ctan.org/pkg/historische-zeitschrift), though I think it is not used that often. (I know, it‘s a shameless self-promotion …)

Comment: One thing you didn't address in your question: Are the .bib file formats compatible? There exists a *huge* infrastructure for bibtex .bib files. Journals usually provide references in bibtex format. There's software to manage bibtex bibliographies. There is emacs support. And of course there are existing bibliographies in bibtex format. The important question is: How much of this do you lose if you use biber instead?

Comment: @celtschk This is a very good question. I could  add some points about this to my answer, but it would actually be good if you asked the question separately, so that the resident `biblatex` experts could all have a chance to weigh in on the issue.

Comment: OK, I'll do so.

Comment: Is there a good visual comparison of those biblatex styles anywhere?

Comment: @naught101 I don't think so.  And there's a lot more to most styles than can be shown with a simple example or two, so I don't know how useful such a resource would be.

Comment: @Johannes_B Not only is biber quite slow, using biblatex can also make pdflatex much slower https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230796/why-does-biber-increase-compilation-time-of-pdflatex-runs-dramatically-factor-2

Comment: @McDuffin biber and pdftex are different tools for different things.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes they are. My point was that there are multiple ways biblatex can have a negative performance impact: both because biber is slower than bibtex, and because using biblatex can actually make the latex compilation phase slower too

Comment: @PhilipM The short answer is, yes, this is quite simple to do in `biblatex` too. But if you're happy with `natbib` and it serves your needs, there's no strong reason to switch to `biblatex`.  `biblatex` excels in handling a lot more reference types, and different sorts of citing practices especially those used in the humanities (although it can do all the things that `natbib` can do too.)  It also has much more sophisticated sorting facilities, which helps for people not writing in English.

Answer (score 185):

Here is a more visual approach based on [Alan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn)'s great answer. This might complete his explanations with a more visual (and "for dummies") approach.

[image]

To use your database (i.e. your `.bib` file) within your LaTeX document, you need an external program to process it — that is, to transform your `.bib` file into a `.tex` understandable one.

Therefor, you can use either `biber` or `BibTeX`. They both use your `.bib` file as input, even if some of its features/fields might be available for `biber` only (e.g. `utf8` encoding, the fields `crossref`, `urldate`, ...).

To display your bibliography and use citing commands, you need to use a LaTeX package. You can use either `biblatex`, or `natbib`. *With the latter, your `.bib` file need to be processed with `BibTeX`.* But if you use `biblatex`, you can process your `.bib` file either with `biber`, or with `BibTeX`.

Note that, as mentioned by PLK in [Compatibility of bibtex and biblatex bibliography files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37156/64454), `biber` supports other database file format than `.bib` (e.g. native integration of Zotero, Mendeley, etc.).

Comment: FWIW, using neither `natbib` nor `biblatex` is an option if `\cite` is enough for you—probably you need more but that should be mentioned for completeness.

Answer (score 52):

Instead of `pdflatex` one can use `lualatex` or `xelatex`:

[image] [image]

Comment: Is there any modification of your first picture if one use `natbib` instead of `biblatex`?

Comment: not really: "biblatex+Style"->`natbib` and `biblatex.bst`->natbib style, eg. `plainnat.bst`

Comment: Wow, very nice picture! Is its code available somewhere?

Answer (score 31):

In his answer, Alan Munn listed the available extra style packages for `biblatex` on CTAN, as of 2011. As of today, the list has expanded to:

1. `biblatex-abnt`: biblatex style for Brazil's ABNT rules
2. `biblatex-anonymous`: A tool to manage anonymous work with biblatex
3. `biblatex-apa`: biblatex citation and reference style for APA
4. `biblatex-authoryear-icomp-tt`: Author-year style with compact multiple-reference-citations and ibidem mechanism for biblatex
5. `biblatex-bookinarticle`: Manage book edited in article
6. `biblatex-bookinother`: Manage book edited in other entry type
7. `biblatex-bwl`: biblatex citations for FU Berlin
8. `biblatex-caspervector`: A simple citation style for Chinese users
9. `biblatex-chem`: A set of biblatex implementations of chemistry-related bibliography styles
10. `biblatex-chicago`: Chicago style files for biblatex
11. `biblatex-dw`: Humanities styles for biblatex
12. `biblatex-fiwi`: biblatex styles for use in German humanities
13. `biblatex-gost`: biblatex support for GOST standard bibliographies
14. `biblatex-historian`: A biblatex style
15. `biblatex-ieee`: Ieee style files for biblatex
16. `biblatex-ijsra`: biblatex style for the International Journal of Student Research in Archaeology
17. `biblatex-iso690`: biblatex style for ISO 690 standard
18. `biblatex-jura`: biblatex stylefiles for German legal literature
19. `biblatex-juradiss`: biblatex stylefiles for German law thesis
20. `biblatex-luh-ipw`: biblatex styles for social sciences
21. `biblatex-manuscripts-philology`: Manage classical manuscripts with biblatex
22. `biblatex-mla`: MLA style files for biblatex
23. `biblatex-morenames`: New names for standard biblatex entry type
24. `biblatex-multiple-dm`: Load multiple datamodels in biblatex
25. `biblatex-musuos`: A biblatex style for citations in musuos.cls
26. `biblatex-nature`: Prepare papers for the journal Nature
27. `biblatex-nejm`: biblatex style for the New England Journal of Medicine (NEJM)
28. `biblatex-nottsclassic`: Citation style for the University of Nottingham
29. `biblatex-opcit-booktitle`: Use op. cit. for the booktitle of a subentry
30. `biblatex-philosophy`: Styles for using biblatex for work in philosophy
31. `biblatex-phys`: A biblatex implementation of the AIP and APS bibliography style
32. `biblatex-publist`: biblatex bibliography support for publication lists
33. `biblatex-realauthor`: Indicate the real author of a work
34. `biblatex-science`: biblatex implementation of the Science bibliography style
35. `biblatex-source-division`: References by “division” in classical sources
36. `biblatex-subseries`: Manages subseries with biblatex
37. `biblatex-swiss-legal`: Bibliography and citation styles following Swiss legal practice
38. `biblatex-trad`: “Traditional” BibTEX styles with biblatex
39. `biblatex-true-citepages-omit`: Correction of some limitation of the citepages=omit option of biblatex styles
40. `citeall`: Cite all entries of a bbl created with biblatex
41. `ecobiblatex`: Global Ecology and Biogeography biblatex styles for the Biber backend
42. `historische-zeitschrift`: biblatex style for the journal 'Historische Zeitschrift'

Comment: Thanks for adding this here, exactly what I needed reading the other answers but didn't make the effort to look it up.

Answer (score 17):

**Other disadvantages of the BibLatex (Biber) vs Bibtex**

I recently moved to biblatex because of some weakness of the bibtex in relation to crossref.  Unfortunately, BibLatex has its own.

1. Only the year will have the link (Why only the year is as a link in \cite reference([biblatex-apa and hyperref: right parenthesis not part of link for \textcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/biblatex-apa-and-hyperref-right-parenthesis-not-part-of-link-for-textcite?s=3|0.7801) ; [Why only the year is as a link in \cite reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212495/why-only-the-year-is-as-a-link-in-cite-reference?s=1|3.4533) )
2. some of the favorite style, the Harvard styles for example, are not natively available for BibLatex ([Harvard Reference using Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102662/harvard-reference-using-biblatex). You need to do a lot of manual work if you want get format like **agsm**.
3. Biber, the backend processor for biblatex is much slower ([Why is biber so slow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53247/why-is-biber-so-slow))
4. Biblatex is not supported by many journals.
5. I have to use more extended texts like **\textcitet** in place of **\citet**. The same extensions are made on other default commands.  The shorter the text, the better. In addition, spell checkers, even the latex aware ones,  pick these extra commands as misspellings.  That is another annoyance.

My final conclusion is, if your problem with bibtex (natbib)is minimal, stick with it. It is faster; and standard for submission.

I am now back to bibtex.

Comment: Please have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_a_Bibliography in general and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: I find the linking capabilities in biblatex limiting: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212495/why-only-the-year-is-as-a-link-in-cite-reference?s=1|3.4533
There are ways around it: but, with their own associated risks (and, I don't like my preamble messed up with some fix for BibLatex).

Comment: 1) Is addressed in [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864) and that is more or less the best we can do since other factors might cause problems when linking more than the year. Ad 2) Indeed, `biblatex` does not come with as many ready-made styles as `biblatex`, one reason is your point (4), another is that many small modifications are easily done and don't warrant a new style package. You might want to keep in mind that 'Harvard style' is more a lose description than a style like APA style or CMS (both of which have are implemented)

Comment: Ad 4) see [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). Ad 5): you could use `natbib=true` to enable `natbib` compatibility mode that allows you to use `\citet` and `\citep`, but of course you could also `\let\citet\textcite` or just use the auto-complete feature of your editor. Your editor should also be able to exclude certain commands from spell-checking.

Comment: But while I don't agree with all your grievances, I more or less agree with your conclusion. If there is nothing wrong with good ol' BibTeX for you, you don't have to switch. But if you need the additional flexibility and capabilities that `biblatex` offers, do by all means go for `biblatex`. (I find that those in mathematics or the natural sciences will probably not need `biblatex` and will get on with BibTeX just fine; but in the humanities `biblatex` comes in really handy.)

Comment: I am also in the humanities. I was very interested at the potentials that BibLatex offers to include names which follow  non-European conventions (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313176/bibtex-biber-how-to-cite-an-author-using-ethiopian-conventions?s=1|0.8974). But, the costs grow faster immediately: my late 2011 started to cry (the fan); has to wait a couple of seconds to see the result. Since i have a habit of processing immediately after changes, biber sucked my old mac. And, the linking (I have seen the solution; but, I don't like it) becomes boring.

Comment: You only need to run Biber if you changed the `.bib` file or cited a reference previously not cited, with tools like `latexmk` you can avoid running it too often. Why don't you like the solutions for the links and think it becomes boring? There are good reasons why the default links are as they are.

Answer (score 11):

In my view there are still a few huge disadvantages to biber.  Mostly these are related to debugging.  Let me list a few of them here:

1. I have a *.bib file that was working fine for 15 years with biblatex and suddenly stopped working under biber.  In fact, it worked for awhile under biber then suddenly stopped.
2. Finding the error was painful for several reasons.  First, there was no error message when I ran biber, yet the problem was really there.  It did not show up until I ran PDFLaTeX a second time.
3. I had to find the error by an 80s style debugging procedure where I kept commenting out cittions. Until everything compiled because the error message was nowhere near the actual error.
4. Moreover, I had to manually delete a bunch of auxiliary files in between compilation.  Why?  Because once the compilation error showed up, it would not go away, EVEN AFTER the error was fixed.  The only way to get it to compile again was to find the invisible error, fix the invisible error, delete all the auxiliary files, compile with pdflatex, run biber, compile again with pdflatex, and open the pdf file and examine it. All of these steps are required after making some change to the file without really knowing beforehand whether that is really the problem.

It was a good way to waste half of a day to find out that the abstract in one of my bibtex references should have had "\%" instead of "%".

Comment: Mhhh, wouldn't it be the same with BibTeX though? Fact is that `%` instead of `\%` is wrong in that it will cause LaTeX to choke badly if it is processed. The issue with auxiliary files also applies to BibTeX. If you had an error in the `.bib` file one re-run of Biber/BibTeX should make sure the resulting `.bbl` file is then correct and the subsequent LaTeX run should be sufficient to check that.

Comment: What strikes me as odd though is that you claim your document used to work (even with Biber) and the suddenly stopped doing so. I would expect this only to happen if the file was changed. (Plus, I think you are being a little unfair saying there are "a few" disadvantages, then using a list with four points, but when it comes down to it, you really have only one complaint.) I have to admit that BibTeX does not choke on a badly formatted abstract while Biber does (but it really is a badly-formatted field, so BibTeX's behaviour is just "courtesy").

Comment: Just in case it happens to somebody else, in absence of _environment_ like texmaker, a fast debug may be possible printing the whole bibliography (`\cite{*}`) from the corrupted `bib` file, then looking where it stops in the final pdf. Where it stops it is near to the corrupting record...

Comment: in case this should happen to you again, it helps to open the bibliography in Emacs and glance over it. An error like using % in the file will show up in the highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

The .bib files can be read by both BibTeX and Biber engines, but the commands in the documents are not the same. The file .bib is common called as a "bibtex" file, but it's an inherited name and should be perceived as having no relation to the BibTeX engine now. Thanks to the `biblatex` package for supporting both engines, commands intended to be used by BibTeX can be used by Biber now.

To sum up, BibTeX and Biber are engines to read bibtex files, biblatex is a package for LaTeX documents.

#### How to do it properly

1. **Making sure the TeX editor running Biber, not BibTeX**
   [Detailed post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/50146)
2. **Running LaTeX → Biber → LaTeX**
   The code should be `\usepackage{biblatex}`, `\addbibresource{filename.bib}` and `\printbibliography`. Don't use `\bibliography` or `\bibliographystyle` as they belong to BibTeX.

Read more: 
[Getting Started with Biblatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/07/31/getting-started-with-biblatex.html)

Comment: This answer would be more apt in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. The top-voted answer already explains the difference between Biber and BibTeX.

Comment: well, I did read it first, but [it wasn't enough for me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/406205/50146) to really understand how to successfully make bibliography in LaTeX. That question is more about how to compile it, with an assumption that the readers have already understood the concepts, hence it doesn't stress enough on the convolution. My first two paragraphs address this (the rest are just bonus), so it's more apt in here I think.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber